# Using jest without ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, es6-modules

Unfurtunately, our web project doesn't use ES6 modules yet. Instead, we transpile our TypeScript sources and then concatenate them all together.

This works well in the browser, and also in Karma and WallabyJS (by setting the `files` option in their configuration file).

Since our 1500 tests takes a long time to execute, I wanted to check Jest. However, our tests fail because jest can't find the types we are importing.

For instance, we have a class named `StringUtils` and the for the following code:

```
import StringUtils = common.utils.StringUtils;

class Person {
    private _name: string;
    address(): string {
        return StringUtils.buildAddress(this);
    }
}
```

We fail with:

```
ReferenceError: common is not defined
```

Is there a way to tell jest what files to load (and in what order) before running tests, like we do with Karma and WallabyJS?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you find a way to solve this without using modules?

Comment: @Perennialista No, but we switched to using modules, so I plan to try and move to jest soon...

Comment: I had the very same problem with a legacy website and we came up with a working solution on this other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039033/configuring-jsdom-in-jest-across-multiple-tests-without-using-modules

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify a [setupTestFrameworkScriptFile](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string) or [setupFiles]([setupTestFrameworkScriptFile](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#setupFiles] which will let you setup some stuff before it starts running your tests.

You would put those in your `package.json`, or a separate file (if you pass it in with a `--config` flag).

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't really work. For instance, modules that require jQuery doesn't really "know" it was loaded and our modules can't find other modules.

It seems files loaded as setupFiles doesn't have `window` as their global object, so they are not updating it properly and other modules can't use them properly.