# Configuring jsdom in Jest across multiple tests without using modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, jsdom

I want to test scripts in an environment where we can not export modules. I have installed Jest version 23.1.0 and there aren't other packages in my `package.json` file. 
Using jsdom ['old' api](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/master/lib/old-api.md) I have come up with a solution that works as expected:

**script.js**

```
var exVar = "test";
```

**script.test.js**

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom/lib/old-api.js');

test('old jsdom api config', function(done) {
    jsdom.env({
        html: "<html><body></body></html>",
        scripts: [__dirname + "/script.js"],
        done: function (err, window) {
            expect(window.exVar).toBe("test");
            done();
        }
    });
});
```

However with this implementation I have to re-write the config for every test, because it looks like the jsdom config gets re-written every time.

**What I have tried**

So far I have tried running this configuration:

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom/lib/old-api.js');
jsdom.env({
    html: "<html><body></body></html>",
    scripts: [__dirname + "/script.js"],
    done: function (err, window) {
        console.log('end');
    }
});
```

with this test:

```
test('old jsdom api config', function(done) {
   expect(window.exVar).toBe("test");
   done();
});
```

in different ways: inside `beforeAll`, inside a script linked through `setupFiles` or through `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` in the Jest configuration object, but still nothing works.

Maybe I could extend `jest-environment` as suggested in the [docs](http://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string), but I have no idea of the syntax I should be using, nor of how to link this file to the tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to my co-worker [Andrea Talon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241558/andrea-talon) I have found a way of using the same setup for different tests (at least inside the same file) using the 'Standard API' (not the 'old API').

Here is the complete test file.

```
const {JSDOM} = require("jsdom")
const fs = require("fs")

// file to test
const srcFile = fs.readFileSync("script.js", { encoding: "utf-8" })

// the window
let window

describe('script.js test', () => {
  beforeAll((done) => {
    window = new JSDOM(``, {
      runScripts: "dangerously"
    }).window

    const scriptEl = window.document.createElement("script")
    scriptEl.textContent = srcFile
    window.document.body.appendChild(scriptEl)
    done()
  })

  test('variable is correctly working', (done) => {
    expect(window.exVar).toBe("test");
    done()
  })

})
```

**Additional setup**

In order to load multiple scripts I have created this function which accepts an array of scripts:

```
function loadExternalScripts (window, srcArray) {
  srcArray.forEach(src => {
    const scriptEl = window.document.createElement("script")
    scriptEl.textContent = src
    window.document.body.appendChild(scriptEl)
  });
}
```

So instead of appending every single script to the `window` variable I can load them by declaring them at the top of the file like this:

```
// files to test
const jQueryFile = fs.readFileSync("jquery.js", { encoding: "utf-8" })
const srcFile = fs.readFileSync("lib.js", { encoding: "utf-8" })
```

and then inside the `beforeAll` function I can load them altogether like this:

```
loadExternalScripts(window, [jQueryFile, srcFile])
```

Comment: From further exploration I have discovered that declaring and configuring a new window is useless, as Jest already does that under the hood. So the first require is useless, declaring the window variable is useless, and assigning a value to window in the beforeAll declaration is useless. The other parts are still needed.

Comment: I have created a GitHub repository with the updated working configuration: https://github.com/gtempesta/jest-without-modules

Comment: This looks daunting. It makes me think that Jest is not the right testing framework for js code that is not formatted into modules.