# How to test static javascript on web pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

I want to test static JavaScript code, preferably with Jest which I use in web applications a lot.

I have a little (Django) project, that has some static JavaScript, lets say in:

```
./app/static/stuff.js
```

which contains some old style classes like this:

```
function Stuff() {
  this.do = function() {return 42};
}
```

Now, I want to test that code there without copying files and without having test files in the same directory and without the need to run that in the browser. So I created an npm module and added jest.

Now I added a test file

```
./__test__/stuff.test.js
```

with the following content

```
require('../app/static/stuff.js');

describe('Stuff', () => {
  if('should do stuff', () => {
    const stuff = new Stuff();
    expect(stuff.do()).toEqual(42);
  }
}
```

This does not work, because `stuff.js` is not a node module. So what I did to get this running in the browser (prod code) and tests itself is the following, which is quite hacky IMO *but works*:

```
function Stuff() {
  this.do = function() {return 42};
}

/* Hack to test this code, global is not available in the browser */
if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    global.Stuff = Stuff;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same without polluting my prod code?

Comment: Jest works best for modular code and isn't suited for such scenarios out of the box. You can evaluate scripts with new JSDOM instance, but it will make more sense to test them together with a page in e2e tests (e.g. Jest+Puppeteer).

Comment: @EstusFlask you might be right. I was just wondering, that if I can make this work in 2.5 ugly lines of code, there might be a more elegant way...

Comment: For reference, I created a FR: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11246

Comment: I see not much value in adding `global`. Using IIFE module and adding things to `window` explicitly would make the code a bit more maintainable, than in current state. No, there's no elegant way because Jest alone isn't the right tool for the job. You need to render non-modular scripts like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039033/configuring-jsdom-in-jest-across-multiple-tests-without-using-modules , and it's far from elegant . Do not import them with `require` because this will make them work differently.